# 3 tier-architecture of a web app when the user is offline

Tags: n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

I want to create the high level (3-tier) architecture diagramm of a mobile app when there is connection to the internet and when not. I know that when there is connection to the web, there will be a 3 components in the diagramm, the web-browser(client), the internet and the server which constitutes of the presentation,application & database layer. How is the diagramm however when there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all distinguish between a native mobile app and a mobile web application - I do think that the architecture can be quite different.

I am going to assume that you are trying to draw an architecture diagram for a mobile web application based on your comments.  Typically, most mobile web applications (in contrast to a native mobile app) will only be useful when there is an internet connection.  Ultimately, this is one of the key weaknesses of building a mobile web application (in contrast to a native mobile application).  (Of course, you can try to do some things with a mobile web application with some 'offline' capabilities - but you'll be quite limited in what can be done.)

If you want to use the MVC model, the browser typically will represent the "View" where the data will be rendered.  The controller will be represented by a backend server - whether it be J2EE, .Net, PHP, Node, Ruby, Python etc.  Finally your model would be best represented as code in your backend server.  I would not tend to call the database layer the "model" - even though that was done in the past.  It's a best practice these days to separate the data model (objects in the server) from the persistence model (database schema).

I know that there is a lot of information here, but I hope this helps a bit.